# controlling where to insert a column in a file using awk

Tags: bash, awk

this is my file:

```
$ cat -v test1
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"
"2015-10-06","731","570","2258243","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-N910U","Business Freedom"
"2015-10-06","556","910","13332272","Samsung Korea","Samsung GT-I9505","$49 Plan"
```

this command adds a column to the end 
`NR==1{$7=q"Data_Volume_MB"q}` add a column name at the end on line1. 
`NR>1{$7=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$7); $7= q $7/(1024*1024)q}1` adds a column at the on line 2 and greater

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$7=q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{$7=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$7); $7= q $7/(1024*1024)q}1' test1
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Data_Volume_MB"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","0.131383"
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","0"
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","0"
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","46.5744"
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","108.486"
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","18.9218"
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","0"
"2015-10-06","731","570","2258243","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-N910U","2.15363"
"2015-10-06","556","910","13332272","Samsung Korea","Samsung GT-I9505","12.7146"
```

How do I control where to insert the column? Lets say i want to insert it before the 2nd last column? 
`NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1);}` this does it for line 1 but I cannot figure out how to do it for lines 2 and greater. Can anyone advise how I can do it for line2 and greater `NR>1{$7=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$7); $7= q $7/(1024*1024)q}1`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1);} NR>1{$7=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$7); $7= q $7/(1024*1024)q}1' test1
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Data_Volume_MB","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","0.131383"
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","0"
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","0"
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","46.5744"
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","108.486"
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","18.9218"
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","0"
"2015-10-06","731","570","2258243","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-N910U","2.15363"
"2015-10-06","556","910","13332272","Samsung Korea","Samsung GT-I9505","12.7146"
```

for line 2 and greater I have tried many attempts, but it is always slightly off. e.g.:

`NR>1{$(NF-1)=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$(NF-1)); $(NF-1)= q $(NF-1)/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1);}1`

---

### EDIT1

#### this was my way which I was getting wrong

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1);} NR>1{$(NF-1)=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$(NF-1)); $(NF-1)= q $(NF-1)/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1);}1' test1 | head -n1 | tr ',' '\n'| cat -n
     1  "Rec_Open_Date"
     2  "MSISDN"
     3  "IMEI"
     4  "Data_Volume_Bytes"
     5  "Device_Manufacturer"
     6  "Data_Volume_MB"
     7  "Device_Model"
     8  "Product_Description"
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1);} NR>1{$(NF-1)=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$(NF-1)); $(NF-1)= q $(NF-1)/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1);}1' test1 | head -n2 | tail -n1 | tr ',' '\n'| cat -n
     1  "2015-10-06"
     2  "427"
     3  "060"
     4  "137765"
     5  "Samsung Korea"
     6  "0.131383"
     7  137765
     8  "$39 Plan"
```

### Answers below from @Etan

### Answer 1 --

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1);} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1);}1' test1 | head -n1 | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "Rec_Open_Date"
     2  "MSISDN"
     3  "IMEI"
     4  "Data_Volume_Bytes"
     5  "Device_Manufacturer"
     6  "Data_Volume_MB"
     7  "Device_Model"
     8  "Product_Description"
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1);} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1);}1' test1 | head -n2 | tail -n1  | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "2015-10-06"
     2  "427"
     3  "060"
     4  "137765"
     5  "Samsung Korea"
     6  "0.131383"
     7  "Samsung SM-G900I"
     8  "$39 Plan"
$
```

### Answer 2 --

#### to insert it after the second last column(working from the second last column)

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) FS q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= $(NF-1) FS q n/(1024*1024)q}1' test1 | head -n1 | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "Rec_Open_Date"
     2  "MSISDN"
     3  "IMEI"
     4  "Data_Volume_Bytes"
     5  "Device_Manufacturer"
     6  "Device_Model"
     7  "Data_Volume_MB"
     8  "Product_Description"
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) FS q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= $(NF-1) FS q n/(1024*1024)q}1' test1 | head -n2 | tail -n1 | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "2015-10-06"
     2  "427"
     3  "060"
     4  "137765"
     5  "Samsung Korea"
     6  "Samsung SM-G900I"
     7  "0.131383"
     8  "$39 Plan"
```

### Answer 3 --

#### to insert it after the second last column(working from the last column)

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$NF=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $NF} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $NF= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $NF;}1' test1 | head -n1 | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "Rec_Open_Date"
     2  "MSISDN"
     3  "IMEI"
     4  "Data_Volume_Bytes"
     5  "Device_Manufacturer"
     6  "Device_Model"
     7  "Data_Volume_MB"
     8  "Product_Description"
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$NF=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $NF} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $NF= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $NF;}1' test1 | head -n2 | tail -n1 | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "2015-10-06"
     2  "427"
     3  "060"
     4  "137765"
     5  "Samsung Korea"
     6  "Samsung SM-G900I"
     7  "0.131383"
     8  "$39 Plan"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace the value at `$(NF-1)` as the first thing you do in the action. Then you try to use `$(NF-1)` as if it still had the original value in it.

That isn't going to work. You need to save the value to another variable, operate on that, and then set `$(NF-1)` to the new value.

```
NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1)}1
```

Also to use the new value as the second to last column you need to place it *after* the value in the second to last column (or operate on the last column and place it before it).

```
NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= $(NF-1) FS q n/(1024*1024)q}1
```

or

```
NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $NF= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $NF;}1
```